# iOS App store statistics split up by app

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes-store

I want to be able to check iOS App store revenue statistics and add new users who can only see the stats for certain apps (e.g. user 1 can see stats for all of the apps in an itunes account, and user 2 can see stats for one 2 or 3 of the apps.)

Is there any system that can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AppFigures.com does it, but it does have a monthly fee.

Comment: AppAnnie.com now does it for free!

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to answer by saying it's not possible as iTunes connect doesn't give you this fine grained level of control over your users.

I'm happy to be proved wrong by someone else who knows of a third party service that can scrape iTunes Connect [AppViz](http://www.ideaswarm.com/AppViz2.html) style and restrict access with it's own auth system.

Comment: I just found AppFigures.com and it does it perfectly, it does cost money, (about $2.00 / month / app).  But it's a pretty good option.